# Set last tableView cell as constant cell among variable cells in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, cell

As the title says, I would like to create a cell which is constant in a tableView where cells are variable. I want this cell to be the last. Actually, all my cells are created with data from Firbase. The last constant cell should be always there. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

You can change only cell at some `indexPath` (last in your case) and set it how you want to.

Here is an example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 8 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lastCell", for: indexPath) as! lastCellClass

          //your code

          return cell

        }else{

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) as! dataCellClass

          //your code

          return cell

        }


    }
```

Do not forget that cells are zero based (indexPath.row 8) is 9th cell.

Note: If your numberOfRows can change you can do:

```
 if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == (yourData.count - 1){ 
   //Here you will get your last cell

}
```

Comment: How can I return multiple cell type? I have to return my constant cell and the other variables cells... ty for the help.

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV I updated my answer to return multiple cells. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: `Value of type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'dequeueReusableCell'`

Comment: ` let Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("yourcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! lastCell` works?

Comment: Sorry I put there worng function now it should work. :) @greenpoisononeTV

Comment: OK the issue I have now is that the "lastCell" overrides the last "dataCell".

Comment: I tried to add 1 the the value of rows like this:  `override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return (self.groupNames.count) + 1
    }`

Comment: OK it works if I do this but if I put `if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == (yourData.count )`     instead of     `if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == (yourData.count - 1)`

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thanks for all this help you're great!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve it many ways.

This is my approach for it. I will create new tableview section for it. Where I will keep the number of rows as one always.
In cell for row at indexpath I will check the condition for that section and will return the corresponding constant cell.

Comment: But if I create a new section, the last cell will be down, after the other cells. You know, if there are 3 cells in a line of 4 cells, The constant cell will not be in the last line place. English isn't my first language so I hope you'll understand me...

Comment: Have the constant cell in section 0 and others in section 1.

Comment: Yes but sections are separated. I want the last cell in the same lines of the first section...